# Install with custom LDE pre-installed

Tags: live-usb, desktop-environments

So I want to set up a bootable usb for a friend who is interested in changing out his OS, but doesn't like the way the way the desktop environment looks or works for Ubuntu. I want to set him up with Budgie or something and make it as smooth as a transition as possible. Anyone know how to set up an ISO with a preloaded custom desktop environment?

Comment: Why not simply use the [Ubuntu budgie iso](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads)?

Comment: Ah, that's perfect, thanks. I'll leave this here in case someone has a similar question about a LDE that doesn't have a pre-made ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use one of the forks of Remastersys (RIP). You might want to do a search and find out what's available at the moment. Remastersys and it's descendants are written in bash, so forking and fixing it is a tempting project for a lot of people. Perhaps that is why the forks seem to come and go as far as active maintenance goes. The one I last had success with is Pinguy:

http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/

Last time I looked there were at least 2 approaches to remastering using programs in the repo. Search "remaster" with Synaptic or something similar. One of those approaches, UCK, was hideously complex compared to the simplicity of the Remastersys way. The other was just plain broke. But it might be worth a look now.